# Group and Sort Dictionary Data in TableViewController with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch, xcode7-beta5

I have a Dictionary data structure like below and I am trying to group them in my TableViewController such that Group A displays **MyData** that starts with **title** = A and at the same time display **sectionIndexTitlesForTableView** with available letters gotten from Title.

[This is my what I want to achieve]

[image: Prototype]

I have tried to scrap off all the first letters from the title Element in my Dictionary and save them in a set using the code below but when I run my app, I get results duplicated in my table.

I am quite new to swift and would be glad to be guided on how to achieve this.

Here's my Dictionary Data:

```
var data: [[String:AnyObject]] =

[
  [
    "id": "1",
    "title": "A Title",
    "alphabet": "A",
    "Detail": "This is a String"
  ],      
  [
    "id": "2",
    "title": "A Title Again",
    "alphabet": "A",
    "Detail": "This is a String"
  ],
  [
    "id": "3",
    "title": "B Title",
    "alphabet": "B",
    "Detail": "This is a String"
  ],
  [
    "id": "4",
    "title": "B Title Again",
    "alphabet": "B",
    "Detail": "This is a String"
  ]
]
```

And Here's my attempt:

```
class Index: UITableViewController {

var MyData = data

var letters = Set<String>()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for element in MyData {
        var title = element["title"] as? String
        let letter = title?.substringToIndex(advance(title!.startIndex, 1))         
        letters.insert(letter!)
    }


  MyData =   MyData.sort { element1, element2 in
        let title1 = element1["title"] as? String
        let title2 = element2["title"] as? String

        return title1 < title2
    }

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return letters.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.MyData.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell?

        cell!.textLabel?.text = (MyData[indexPath.row]["title"] as! String)

    return cell!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `numberOfRowsInSection` has to return the number of rows per section, in your example 2 for section 0 and 2 for section 1

You can collect your letter set with the key value coding method `valueForKey` which is often mistaken for `objectForKey`.
Unlike `objectForKey` which returns one value for the given key `valueForKey` returns the value of the key `alphabet`of all members in the array.

This code creates a `Set` of the letters to purge the duplicates, turns it back to an `Array` and sorts it.

```
let letters = (data as NSArray).valueForKey("alphabet") as! [String]
let filteredLetters = Set<String>(letters)
let sortedLetters = Array(filteredLetters).sorted {$0 < $1}
```

If all values for `alphabet` – as well as the other keys - are guaranteed to be `String` there is no need to cast them to optionals.

Then in `numberOfRowsInSection` you have to filter the number of items of each section

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return data.filter { ($0["alphabet"] as! String) == sortedLetters[section] }.count
}
```

Notice that there is no casting needed for the expression `sortedLetters[section]` because the compiler knows that's an array of `String`.

Of course you have also to retrieve the appropriate items for the sections in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which is quite expensive because the main array is going to be filtered multiple times.
I'd recommend to transform `data` in `viewDidLoad()` into a new dictionary with the letters as keys and an array containing the items starting with this particular letter as values. This is the best solution regarding speed and performance.

Here a complete solution (without displaying the letters for quick search)

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

  let data: [[String:String]] =

  [
    [
      "id": "1",
      "title": "A Title",
      "alphabet": "A",
      "Detail": "This is a String"
    ],
    [
      "id": "2",
      "title": "A Title Again",
      "alphabet": "A",
      "Detail": "This is a String"
    ],
    [
      "id": "3",
      "title": "B Title",
      "alphabet": "B",
      "Detail": "This is a String"
    ],
    [
      "id": "4",
      "title": "B Title Again",
      "alphabet": "B",
      "Detail": "This is a String"
    ]
  ]


  var letters = [String]()
  var dataSource = [String:AnyObject]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for value in data  {
      let letter = value["alphabet"]!
      if dataSource[letter] == nil {
        letters.append(letter)
        dataSource[letter] = [[String:AnyObject]]()
      }
      var array = dataSource[letter] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
      array.append(value)
      dataSource.updateValue(array, forKey: letter)
    }
    letters.sorted {$0 < $1}
    tableView.reloadData()

  }

  // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return letters.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let letter = letters[section]
    return dataSource[letter]!.count
  }


  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let letter = letters[indexPath.section]
    let letterArray = dataSource[letter]! as! [[String:AnyObject]]
    let item = letterArray [indexPath.row]
    if let title = item["title"] as? String {
      cell.textLabel?.text = title
    }
    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return letters[section]
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I wish you would guide in relation to my code so as to make me understand better. I am just a complete Beginner at Swift.

Comment: Your code cannot work this way and it's too complicated to provide a solution based on your code. I'll post a complete solution